# Probability in multi-user operating system

Tags: math, probability

In a multi-user Operating System,20 requests are made to use a particular resourse per hour,on an average.The probability that no requests are made in 45 minutes is:

A). e^-15

B).e^-5

C).1-e^-5

D). 1-e^-10

I have spent time on wikipideia and several other sites but none of them clearly figured out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stochastic process you are describing is a Poisson process. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_process):

> In probability theory, a Poisson process is a stochastic process that counts the number of events and the time points at which these events occur in a given time interval. The time between each pair of consecutive events has an exponential distribution with parameter λ and each of these inter-arrival times is assumed to be independent of other inter-arrival times.

Since the [exponential distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) is [memoryless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Memorylessness), we can define T to be an exponentially-distributed random variable that represents the time until the next event.

What should the expectation of T be? You have described a process in which the rate of events is 20 per hour. This is every 3 minutes. So E[T] = λ<sup>-1</sup> = 3 min and thus λ = 1/3 min<sup>-1</sup>.

Now you are asking the question "What is the probability that no events occur in the next 45 minutes?" This is P(T > 45 min).

> P(T > 45 min) = 1 - P(T ≤ 45 min) = 1 - (1 - e<sup>-45 min × λ</sup>) = e<sup>-15</sup>

This uses the fact that the cumulative density function for the exponential distribution is P(T ≤ t) = 1 - e<sup>-λt</sup>.